# Calling via adb in PowerShell

Tags: android, powershell, adb

As you may know, the command for calling via adb is:

```
.\adb.exe shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL tel:"656565"
```

This works well but when I use textbox, it takes garbage value...

```
.\adb.exe shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL tel:$textbox1.Text
```

I have tried this also but failed

```
$button21_Click={
#TODO: Place custom script here

$textbox1.Clear
.\adb.exe shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL tel:$textbox1.Text
}
```

Please help

Comment: You forgot your `"`'s?

Comment: thanks for replying....where should i add 's.?

Comment: In your example you wrote the call with `tel:"656565"` but your PS script will generate `tel:656565`

Comment: what u r telling it works ...but when i take input in textbox then it calls to a  random  number  instead of my number

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, it is still a little unclear from your question, but you could try something like this to capture the value in a variable and then use that:

```
$button21_Click = {
  $tel = "tel:" + '"' + $textbox1.Text + '"'
  $textbox1.Clear()
  .\adb.exe shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL $tel
}
```